# leave one out testing

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, cross-validation

I am currently working with a small dataset of 20x300. Since I have so few datapoints, I was wondering if I could use an approach similar to leave-one-out cross-validation but for testing.

Here's what I was thinking:

1. train/test split the data, with only one data point in the test set.
2. train the model on training data, potentially with
   grid_search/cross-validation
3. use the best model from step 2 to
   make a prediction on the one data point and save the prediction in
   an array
4. repeat the previous steps until all the data points have
   been in the test set
5. calculate your preferred metric of choice
   (accuracy, f1-score, auc, etc) using these predictions

The pros of this approach would be to:

- You don't have to "reserve/waste" data for testing so you can train
  with more datapoints.

The cons would be:

- This approach suffers from potential(?) data leakage.
- You are calculating an accuracy metric from a bunch of predictions
  that potentially came from different models, due to the gridsearches, so I'm not sure how accurate it is going to be.

I have tried the standard approaches of train/test splitting but since I need to take out at least 5 points for testing, then I don't have enough points for training and the ROC AUC becomes very bad.

Here's come code so you can see what I'm talking about.

```
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):

    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    param_grid = {'C': [1e2, 5e2, 1e3, 5e3, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5, 5e6, 1e6],
              'gamma': [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.1, 1],
                  'degree': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                 'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear', 'poly'],
                 'class_weight': ['balanced', None]}

    model = SVC(probability = True)

    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=num_cv_folds)

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid,
            n_jobs=-1,
            cv=skf,
            scoring='roc_auc',
            verbose=0,
            refit=True,
            iid=False)

    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

    best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_
    y_pred_test = best_model.predict_proba(X_test)

    y_preds.append(y_pred_test[0][0])

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y, y_preds_, pos_label=1)
auc_roc1 = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

I would really appreciate some feedback about whether this approach is actually feasibly or not and why.

Comment: I suggest you to perform a data agumentation of your dataset and then split the dataset into train / validation / test . I think that your approach could lead to overfit your model.

Comment: I was able to get 0.9 auc with a p-value of 2% in permutation testing so the results are good at least. I'm just concerned that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong from a statistical point of view. What kind of augmentation would you suggest?